# DISABLING VOIDS IN ARDUINO

Tags: arduino

Ok, basically I'm trying to enable and disable voids in the code. Here is the code:
what I'm trying to create here is a dimmer. I want to enable and disable some of the voids to create that. Also when the value of "brightness" changes in one of the "for" loops, I can't transfer that value to other loops. Please help

```
int sensorPin = A0; 
int sensorValue = 0; 
int LED = 10;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); 
pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {

sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin); 
Serial.println(sensorValue); 



if ( analogRead < 30){
  Down() = false;
}
if ( analogRead > 31) {
  Up() = false;
}
}

void Up () {
  for ( int brightness = 0; sensorValue < 30; brightness = brightness + 5 ) {
  analogWrite(LED, brightness);
  delay(100);
}

}

void Down () {
  for ( int brightness = brightness; sensorValue > 31; brightness = brightness - 5 ) {
  analogWrite(LED, brightness);
  delay(100);
}
}
```

Comment: Also, When one of the foor lops are executed, the sensorvalue stops updating

Comment: What do you mean with "void"? And this does not give any compiling errors: `Down() = false;` ?

Comment: I mean that I'm trying disable/enable "void Down()" and "void Up()". also "Down() = false;) gives the following error, "Down was not declared in this scope

Comment: `void Down(void)` and `void Up(void)` are 2 functions. This means that every time you call `Down()', the code inside this function is executed. You can't remove void, since this mean that this function does not return any value.

Comment: what about updating the value of brightness through loop functions?

Comment: Ok, I try to write the code in the right manner...

Comment: please, take a coding course

Answer (score 0):

Still does not know what you want do.

But if I undestand it right (from the comments), the code should be:

```cpp
int sensorPin = A0; 
int sensorValue = 0; 
uint8_t lightBrightness = 0;
int LED = 10;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin); 
  // Serial.println(sensorValue); 
  if ( sensorValue < 30){
    if(lightBrightness < 255) lightBrightness++;
    analogWrite(LED, lightBrightness );
  }

  if ( sensorValue > 31) {
    if(lightBrightness > 0) lightBrightness--;
    analogWrite(LED, lightBrightness );
  }

  delay(100); // << just to see fading the light
}
```